# a4j:commandLink executes action after double clicking

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have a table of users with an `a4j:commandLink` which deletes the corresponding user, but the problem is that I need to click twice for the action to execute, how can I solve it, here's the code:

```
            <h:form id="formUsuariosRegistrados">
                <rich:dataScroller for="usersTable" fastControls="hide"
                                   boundaryControls="hide" />
                <rich:dataTable id="usersTable" rows="10" var="user"
                                value="#{administrationBean.tablaUsuarios}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <rich:columnGroup>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Nombre"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Usuario"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Dependencia"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Email"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Tipo usuario"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Tipo dependencia"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Fecha límite"/>
                            </rich:column>
                            <rich:column>
                                <h:outputText value=""/>
                            </rich:column>
                        </rich:columnGroup>
                    </f:facet>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.nombre}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.usuario}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.dependencia}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.correo}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.tipoUsuario}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.tipoDependencia}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.fechaLimiteCarga}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <a4j:commandLink value="Eliminar" immediate="true"
                                         execute="@form"
                                         onclick="return confirm('Esta seguro(a) que deseea continuar?')"
                                         render="@form :formFechaLimite :formModificarContrasena"
                                         action="#{administrationBean.doEliminarUsuario(user.usuario)}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:dataTable>
            </h:form>
```

**UPDATE**

Here's another piece of code that I added to the same view, but now happen two things:

1. When View is first loaded, if I click on the `a4j:commandLink` on the table, the action gets called fine.
2. After doing 1, when I try to check (or uncheck) the `<h:sekectBooleanCheckBox>` now this component executes ajax after clicking twice.
3. I tried what BalusC's answers says but I think I am not doing it right with this new form.

   Please advise, cheers

   ```
       <h:form id="formFechaLimite">
           <rich:panel style="width: 400px" id="panelFechaLimite">
               <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Fecha limite de carga"/>
               </f:facet>

               <h:outputLabel for="fechaLimite" value="Fecha Limite"/>
               <br/>
               <rich:calendar id="fechaLimite"
                              value="#{administrationBean.fechaLimite}"
                              datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                   <a4j:ajax event="change" render="usuarios fechaLimiteModificada"
                             listener="#{administrationBean.doHideEtiquetaFechaModificada}"/>
               </rich:calendar>
               <br/>
               <h:outputLabel for="todosUsuarios"
                              value="Aplicar a todos los usuarios? "/>
               <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="todosUsuarios"
                                        value="#{administrationBean.fechaTodosUsuarios}">
                   <a4j:ajax event="change" render="usuarios fechaLimiteModificada"
                             listener="#{administrationBean.doCheckBoxChanged}"/>
               </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
               <br/>
               <a4j:outputPanel id="usuarios">
                   <rich:select value="#{administrationBean.selectedUser}"
                                defaultLabel="Seleccione un usuario..."
                                rendered="#{not administrationBean.fechaTodosUsuarios}">
                       <f:selectItems value="#{administrationBean.selectUser}"/>
                       <a4j:ajax event="selectitem" render="fechaLimiteModificada"
                                 listener="#{administrationBean.doHideEtiquetaFechaModificada}"/>
                   </rich:select>
               </a4j:outputPanel>
               <br/><br/>
               <a4j:commandButton value=" Aplicar " execute="@form"
                                  render="@form :panelUsuarios :formUsuariosRegistrados :usersTable"
                                  action="#{administrationBean.doCambiarFechaLimite}"/>
               <a4j:outputPanel id="fechaLimiteModificada">
                   <h:outputText value="Fecha límite modificada !"
                                 rendered="#{administrationBean.renderedEtiquetaFechaModicada}"
                                 style="color: #D17100; font-size: 14px;"/>
               </a4j:outputPanel>
           </rich:panel>
           <br/>
       </h:form>

       <br/>

       <rich:panel style="width: 800px" id="panelUsuarios">
           <f:facet name="header">
               <h:outputText value="Administración de usuarios"/>
           </f:facet>
           <h:form id="formUsuariosRegistrados">
               <rich:dataScroller for="usersTable" fastControls="hide"
                                  boundaryControls="hide" />
               <rich:dataTable id="usersTable" rows="10" var="user"
                               value="#{administrationBean.tablaUsuarios}">
                   <f:facet name="header">
                       <rich:columnGroup>
                           <rich:column>
                               <h:outputText value="Nombre"/>
                           </rich:column>
                           <rich:column>
                               <h:outputText value="Usuario"/>
                           </rich:column>
                           <rich:column>
                               <h:outputText value="Dependencia"/>
                           </rich:column>
                           <rich:column>
                               <h:outputText value="Email"/>
                           </rich:column>
                           <rich:column>
                               <h:outputText value="Tipo usuario"/>
                           </rich:column>
                           <rich:column>
                               <h:outputText value="Tipo dependencia"/>
                           </rich:column>
                           <rich:column>
                               <h:outputText value="Fecha límite"/>
                           </rich:column>
                           <rich:column>
                               <h:outputText value=""/>
                           </rich:column>
                       </rich:columnGroup>
                   </f:facet>
                   <rich:column>
                       <h:outputText value="#{user.nombre}"/>
                   </rich:column>
                   <rich:column>
                       <h:outputText value="#{user.usuario}"/>
                   </rich:column>
                   <rich:column>
                       <h:outputText value="#{user.dependencia}"/>
                   </rich:column>
                   <rich:column>
                       <h:outputText value="#{user.correo}"/>
                   </rich:column>
                   <rich:column>
                       <h:outputText value="#{user.tipoUsuario}"/>
                   </rich:column>
                   <rich:column>
                       <h:outputText value="#{user.tipoDependencia}"/>
                   </rich:column>
                   <rich:column>
                       <h:outputText value="#{user.fechaLimiteCarga}"/>
                   </rich:column>
                   <rich:column>
                       <a4j:commandLink value="Eliminar" immediate="true"
                                        execute="@form"
                                        ondblclick="return confirm('Esta seguro(a) que deseea continuar?')"
                                        render="@form :formFechaLimite :formModificarContrasena"
                                        action="#{administrationBean.doEliminarUsuario(user.usuario)}"/>
                   </rich:column>
               </rich:dataTable>
           </h:form>

           <br/>

       </rich:panel>
   ```

Comment: Is the form or one of its parents been re-rendered/updated by an ajax request from another form beforehand?

Comment: Yes, I have another form that registers users and this table gets refreshed every time a new user is registered. is my approach a bad practice? or how can I avoid the double clicking? I read something about a bug on JSF 2.1 could it be that bug?

Comment: Update my question. I'm missing something ... I put the parent IDs but still don't get the behavior I want, I'm very frustrated ! Is there a way to see how's the state of some View or something that could just help me right away on detecting what ID I'm missing on `render` attribute?

Comment: This is a different problem. Checkboxes (and radiobuttons) always change only on 2nd click. On 1st click there's no means of a change. You need to replace `event="change"` in `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` by `event="click"` or just remove it altogether. It defaults to the right event already. In the future please ask a new question instead of reusing an old one.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC I'll check that. I thought it was related to the same problem so I posted on this. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the other form wherein you're updating the shown form with the table, make sure that you include the client ID of the form in the ajax `render`. Otherwise the updated form will lose its view state and thus nothing will be processed on 1st submit. After the 1st submit the form get its view state back and subsequent submits will be processed successfully.

E.g.

```html
<h:form>
  ...
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":otherPanel :otherForm" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup id="otherPanel">
    ...
    <h:form id="otherForm">
        ...
    </h:form>
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

This problem is related to [JSF spec issue 790](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-790) and is fixed for the upcoming JSF 2.2. PrimeFaces 3.x doesn't have this problem as its modified JSF ajax engine has already taken this into account.

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF2 - Ajax rendering of content which contains another form](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm.)

Comment: Thanks @BalusC always great help. Very good luck with OmniFaces BTW !