# h:selectOneMenu's f:selectItems not rendering on pop-up display

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have pop-up with `h:selectOneMenu`. This pop-up will be displayed on `a4j:commandLink` click.

`h:selectOneMenu` has "value" attribute is not getting called on pop-up render (I debugged it using System.out.println()).

Because of this value is not being updated on pop-up display, I am seeing last operation value, even though I want to see empty list on new operation.

Any suggestions?

Note: Another observation is, if "add" some button in pop-up which refreshes the h:selectOneMenu, then it is working fine.

My code looks something like this:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="CModalPanel"
                 autosized="true"
                 resizeable="false"
                 moveable="true" domElementAttachment="parent">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Select list"/>
    </f:facet>

    <h:form id="cListID">
       <a4j:outputPanel id="panelID">
    <h:panelGroup>
           <h:selectOneMenu id="cListMenu"
                       value="#{myBean.currvalue}" >                        
                <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.plistItems}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup>
             <a4j:commandLink id="refreshButton" 
                         actionListener="#{anotherBean.addMethod}"
                         render=":cListID" >

             </a4j:commandLink>
     </h:panelGroup>
</a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the content of `<rich:popupPanel>` before opening it.

```
<a4j:commandLink ... render=":cListID" oncomplete="#{rich:component('CModalPanel')}.show()" />
```

Comment: Hi BalusC, I did that, but somehow the other button I have in pop-up which refreshes same pop-up is not working now. Any input?

Comment: You need to make sure that you explicitly include the client ID of the `<h:form>` in the `render`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807640/a4jcommandlink-executes-action-after-double-clicking/10807953#10807953

Comment: Hi BalusC, I tried with form client ID also, please see my updated code in original question, I tried :cListID as well as :cListID:panelID in render attribute. None of those options refreshing the form.

Comment: Hi, since you marked the answer accepted, may I assume that the particular problem has been solved? Perhaps you were using the wrong client ID.

Comment: Just listing form ID in render isn't enough (it seems), I had to add the panel ID also and some other richfaces related bugs causing this issue. I was able to make it work with some trail and error changes in clientID. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

here's a related bug https://community.jboss.org/thread/169542